# Run multi-thread at a time and make thread to run fast

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to run two different threads at a time, but unable to do that. Thread_1 & Thread_2 runs, but difference between them is around 500ms. I am not using `wait()` or `sleep()` anywhere in my code.

Questions:

1. How to make run thread simultaneously or in parallel?
2. How to make thread run fast?

For second question this I used `Thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)` but time difference between other is same.

### Updated with example code

Doing same as below example, but takes more time between both threads to run.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    MyThread thread1 = new MyThread("thread1: ");
    MyThread thread2 = new MyThread("thread2: ");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    boolean thread1IsAlive = true;
    boolean thread2IsAlive = true;
    do {
       if (thread1IsAlive && !thread1.isAlive()) {
           thread1IsAlive = false;
            System.out.println("Thread 1 is dead.");
       }
       if (thread2IsAlive && !thread2.isAlive()) {
           thread2IsAlive = false;
           System.out.println("Thread 2 is dead.");
       }
    } while(thread1IsAlive || thread2IsAlive);
}
```

I have searched the web and gone through some docs. What can I try next?

Comment: Post the code, we can help you with your problem without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: @Arkain I dint post my code, but for example look at this code.I am trying exactly same

Comment: Not running the create/monitor thread as a do..while CPU loop may well help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make run thread simultaneously or in parallel?

As a programmer it's only possible on multi processor machines. On single processor only one thread will run at one time and it's upto JVM (and OS) to choose which thread to run.

> How to make thread run fast ?

You can try (as you did), but overall control is with JVM (and OS) only.

However, increasing the priority of thread doesn't mean that it'll run fast. it only makes chances for the thread to run more frequently than other threads. i.e. OS may (or may not)choose it more no. of times than other threads.

Go through this [link](http://lass.cs.umass.edu/~shenoy/courses/fall01/labs/talab2.html) for some more details. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816011/what-is-the-jvm-scheduling-algorithm) too.

Comment: your right, depends on OS but there can be a way to handle it.

Comment: Technically true that only one thread can be run at a time on a single core CPU, however the OS will switch between all threads rapidly, which give the illusion of parallel execution.

Comment: yup. Technically your right. depends on OS how it run the thread. I tried using CyclicBarrier . Then too dint get it

Comment: @TechEnd: unfortunately (or fortunately) there is not. it's JVM and OS's call entirely.

Comment: yup.. your right sir. Then too make run thread faster what else I can try ??

Comment: Stop wasting one core on monitoring?

Comment: run only your program on system.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure about it nor you can do it.You call thread.start() to start a thread.But it depends on OS when it will be started.Even with setting priority you can't exactly achieve this.

Comment: I am calling Thread_1.start() and Thread_1.start() simultaneously to run. But difference between both timing I want to remove it.

Comment: You can't do this.Because OS defines when and how thread will be executed.You can pass your idea to os by setting priority that one has priority over other.But OS defines what it would do.

Comment: ohk.. then there is no other way to do this ??