# Context switching in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

In a multi-threaded Java application, if I want to identify the instructions where the context switch from one thread to another happens, what is the best approach? Instrumenting every instruction to identify what thread is executing the instruction will give a close approximation. For example, if the switch happens after the instrumentation is executed and before the actual instr. is executed, then the result will be imprecise.

- Is there a way to precisely identify the context switch location (which will be different for different runs) in Java?
- What is the most cost effective of identifying this?

Comment: You can't do this in Java code.  You should be able to accomplish this with profiler hooks.  Care to explain _why_ you need this information?

Comment: I fear you don't understand threading or context switching. This function is performed in combination by the JVM and the Operating System. In particular context-switching is likely performed by the Operating System in mutex-related calls (e.g. `futex` on Linux). Java has no control over this. While it _is_ possible to write your own context-switching application (saving the stack in the middle of your application) to emulate threads there is no actual need to do this apart from self edification (but I've gone there and it was very edifying - but not in Java, it was C and assembler).

Comment: @Gray: I need to do this to perform some analysis. 
PP: Thanks for your comments on my understanding of threading.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question is `You can not do it in java`.It is the resposibility of JVM to switch the context based on underlying operating system and memory model.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

Comment: Isn't the OS responsible for context switching the threads as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827332/how-to-schedule-java-threads?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Most context switching are caused by external interrupts (including timer). It can happen at `any` instruction. Indeed, distribution is not even, but very random. Even if you could collect probability distribution of context switching for every instruction, how would you use it? Looks like you try to solve some problem with inadequate means. Better tell what your real problem is, and we try to suggest a solution.